How do I row reduce this matrix?
I'm not sure how to row reduce this matrix. The given solution is very different from what I calculated. I have done the following so far:

kept the first row as is
R3 = R3 - R1
R2 = R2 / 1
R3 = R3 + 3*R2
R3 = R3 / 2

A walkthrough would be helpful. Thanks.
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 7\\
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$
Given solution:
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -3 & 5\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$
this is the given problem along with the solution

What have you tried so far?

Welcome to MSE. In this forum you're expected to show some effort in order to get help. Edit your question to include your work on the problem in order to avoid your question to be downvoted and eventually closed. This is not a homework service.

just edited to include what i've done so far

Did you really mean $R_2 = R_2/1$?

The matrices are not even the same size. There's obviously something very wrong with the settings of the question.

I attached additional information for context

The first thing you should notice is that the problem uses $x_5$ but there is no $x_4$, and the solution uses $x_4$ but not $x_5$. That's probably a typo which explain the different size of the matrices.

Now, to the point of your question: you are right, the given solution is wrong.

So, let's rewrite the matrix once again.
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 7\\
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
We can see that we are already close to having a 3×3 identity matrix on the LHS (to reduce it to row-echelon form). So, we multiply R2 by -1, and subtract R1 from R3 to get a new row R3.
By doing this, we get
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -2 & -7\\
0 & -3 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
Now, to get rid of the -3, we add 3R2 to R3 to get a new R3.
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -2 & -7\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & -5 & -16
\end{bmatrix}
Finally, we divide R3 by a half to get the leading 1.
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -2 & -7\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -2.5 & -8
\end{bmatrix}
Now, to get rid of the 3 in R1, we subtract 3R2 from R1, and get
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 21\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -2 & -7\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -2.5 & -8
\end{bmatrix}
Which is the final answer. Unfortunately the answer you provided is not the same as this one since the one you gave is wrong. The dimensions of your 2 matrices don't match. So make sure that you're looking at the right answer and compare it with what I provided you here.
I hope this helps!
